# How to Trace Procedure execution time?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have some procedures which are not optimized . I want to analyse that whether these procedures get optimised or not , as there are only not bulk data to check.

I want to put a sql query into all the procedure which will insert in to one table that what is exact time taken by the above query to execute. I will create a table in which my procedure will insert the query execution time.

Is there any way that I can do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to integrate it in your procedure, set a variable which stores the execution start time at the beginning, and a subtract it with the current time at the end of the procedure.

```
/* Start of your procedure */
Declare @startTime datetime = GETDATE()
Declare @duration varchar

/* Your procedure */
...

/* End of your procedure */
Set @duration = CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE() - @startTime,108)
Insert into statisticTable 
Values ('procedureName', @duration)
```

Comment: And instead of hardcoding `'procedureName'` you can use `OBJECT_NAME(@@PROCID)`. I wrote a little about this here (but I didn't get to logging procedure times): http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2003/simple-process-to-track-and-log-sql-server-stored-procedure-use/

Comment: Why convert this to a VARCHAR()?  Why not just store it as a DateTime?  Storing dates and times as strings just introduces possible problems later on.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the **SQL Profiler**?

In Trace Properties you can can define `Start Time` and `End time` of Stored Procedures. It is a very powerful tool.

Comment: Thanks Pabloker. I know about sql profiler but I will have to do the manual effort for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can check above mentioned stuffs using [Dynamic Management Views](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188754.aspx)....

If you are using old version of SQL SERVER, use SQL Server Profiler....

Comment: The DMVs like `sys.dm_exec_procedure_stats` (that one introduced in SQL Server 2008 IIRC) only have aggregates, so be aware that if your system has high uptime or the procedures get called a lot, it may take a long time to see things like average etc. to normalize to the new version of the procedure.

Answer (score -1):

Why would you want to do that?There are plenty of tools like DMV's ,trace ,exevents etc. You will add to overhead to your proc if you put that kind of code. For procedure best is dm_procedure_stats DMV but is availble in 2008 R2 and above only.Use the dm_exec_query_stats for older versions. These will give you much better stats about the time,logical io,cputime, and physical IO's etc.